# what is meant by item-type be presented by ony one field/member

Tags: c

Information about shelf and compartment should be stored as two integer values (one for the shelf number and one for the compartment number) but should in the item-type be presented by only one field/member (you will therefore need to define a new type for the place).

```
struct GrocaryItem{

    char productName[20];
    float amount;
    char unit[10];
    char FileName[30];
};

struct ShoppingList{

    int length;
    struct GrocaryItem *itemList;

};
```

How can I do it? Can I just write...

```
    struct GrocaryItem{

    char productName[20];
    float amount;
    char unit[10];
    char FileName[30];
};

struct ShoppingList{

    int length;
    struct GrocaryItem *itemList;
    struct ExtraInfo *ShelfCompartment;

};

struct ExtraInfo {

    int shelf;
    int compartment;
};
```

Comment: The location needs to be represented *in the item-type* by one member.  I take "item-type" to refer to `struct GroceryItem`, so where in that structure is the location information carried?  You have defined a new type as instructed, but you have not yet used it for anything.

Comment: can you write any example I do not understand properly @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 2):

You could add the new field in the struct representing the item so that if you have a `GrocaryItem` variable `x` you can do `x.info.shelf` or `x.info.compartment`.

```
struct ExtraInfo {
    
        int shelf;
        int compartment;
};


struct GrocaryItem{

    char productName[20];
    float amount;
    char unit[10];
    char FileName[30];
    struct ExtraInfo info;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the solution, if you wanted to pass that value as one integer and print it as two, this would be a great use of a `union`. Especially useful if it's going to be a primary key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

union ExtraInfo {
    struct { uint16_t shelf, compartment; } split;
    uint32_t together;
};

struct GroceryItem {
    union ExtraInfo info;
    char productName[20];
    float amount;
    char unit[10];
    char FileName[30];
};

int main(void) {
    union ExtraInfo a = { 10, 10 }, b = { 8, 10 };
    printf("They are %s.\n",
        a.together == b.together ? "the same" : "different");
    return 0;
}
```

The shopping list should generally not modify the `GroceryItem`. This way you break the dependency on `GroceryItem`, only storing a reference. If one were to serialize the shopping list, (into a file, for example,) one could store the `ExtraInfo` of the `GroceryItem`, assuming it is unique, like a synecdoche.

```
struct ShoppingListItem {
    struct GroceryItem *item;
    int amount;
};

struct ShoppingList {
    size_t size;
    struct ShoppingListItem *items;
};
```